# Highcharts: Column chart with empty data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created chart with dynamic data. And it is getting null values for 2 columns.

see this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/xj6ms/2/

I want to remove empty columns, so that it will arrange other columns properly.

Is it possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the entries in your data with null y values.

This is basic javascript programming, but one way is to create a new array using the non-null entries in the old data array:

```
newdata = [];
for (i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++) {
    if (data[i].y != null) {
        newdata.push(data[i]);
    }        
}
```

You can then use newdata in your chart in place of the data variable:

http://jsfiddle.net/fYcb9/

Comment: How do I do that? I am not getting where to write that function to remove column. Can you please help me in that?

Comment: Steve, great Solution... Thank you very much.. But, when we click on one of the column, and drilled down, it messes up the things... Any idea?

Comment: Steve, I got the answer.. I changed setdata function in click event to pass newdata. now it is working fine.